# Adding Facebook Like and Comment Button in Windows Phone 7 Application

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

We are working on a new game to be deployed in Windows Phone 7. A Facebook page has been created for this purpose and we want to do the following Operations:

a. Create a Like button for the page in Facebook
b. Scores should be shared in that page.

We have downloaded the SDK provided by the Codeplex.com but we are clueless when it comes using this page in that. Please let us know how to go about it

Regards
Biju Melayil

Comment: what SDK did you download? What do you mean with "this page in that" ?

Comment: I have created a page "My Game page" in facebook account and i want to integrate that page with my application. so if they click the like page then it should get updated in that game page.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow to 'like' anything through the API, regardless of the SDK you're using.

Maybe you could use the [usual like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) in an embedded WebBrowser control to guide the user through the liking process.